VS2022 and Unity 2022 UWP Build Issues
I recently updated my Unity installation from v2021 to v2022 LTS and since then, I am unable to build any UWP projects out to appx's in Visual Studio. I've tried multiple versions of Unity 2022 and they all produce the same result. The Unity build completes without issue, but once I open the generated solution file in VS and try to deploy or publish to appx, it fails. If I revert a project back to Unity 2021, everything continues to work as expected. This is true for all deployment types (Debug, Release, etc.) and all architectures (ARM, x64). The errors that are thrown and the output in Visual Studio is reproduced below for a blank Unity project that contains only the Main Camera and default light.



Check if the Windows Build Support (IL2CPP) module is installed for Unity 2022:


Yes, Windows build support is enabled and the Unity build completes successfully, only the Visual Studio deployment/appx publishing fails

Hi,
Visual Studio 2022 has updates in standard C++ headers, which can cause parts of the IL2CPP runtime to fail to compile in some versions of Unity - https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/il2cpp-windows-builds-fails-when-using-vs-2022-17-dot-4-0-preview.  Here's my functional environment:
VS 2022 17.11.5 and Unity 2022.3.48f1c1.
Please also check if the Desktop development with C++ is installed on VS 2022.

Thanks for the response. I'm currently trying to build in Unity 2022.3.51f1 with VS 17.9.6. When run my VS installer, it says that the installation is up to date and cannot update to 17.11. I'm assuming there isn't much difference in these versions though? I followed the issue tracker to the workaround at https://discussions.unity.com/t/workaround-for-building-with-il2cpp-with-visual-studio-2022-17-4/898800, but it did not resolve the issue. Attempting an appx build still produces the same result noted above.

And yes, I have Desktop Development with C++ installed in VS

Hi, I tried using VS 2022 17.11.5 and Unity 2022.3.51f1, and the build was successful. Could you try updating your VS version or provide more information?

Is there a means to force an update? I work on a computer managed by my company, so I have limited control, but when I go to VS, it states that everything is up to date and doesn't give me an option to update.
